# JUnit tests cannot be automatically discovered by VSCode test explorer in my Java gradle project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I imported a Java gradle project into VSCode. There are many JUnit tests in the project under subfolder test. But in the test explorer there are no tests listed.
When I clicked the 'Run Tests' button on the test explorer, a information window popped up in the bottom right corner showing 'Searching tests...', and after searching no tests were found. But, if I manually open a specific test file in the project, then I can run the tests in the test file. So, this means that I can run the tests in a file, but cannot run all the tests in batch from test explorer.
Does anyone know how the test explorer search for the JUnit tests, and how to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Some pictures for this problem.

- About the tests in test explorer:

  [No test are listed in test explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1d5A.png)

   [Searching information after click 'Run tests'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZuxS.png)

  [After searching, there is 0 tests in test explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGk4z.png)
- About the specific test class:

  [There is the test menu in test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n10hh.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.Could you, please, attach a sample project reproducing the error. Or could you create another project reproducing error? Or could you provide some pictures and instructions that can't start the testing Explorer correctly

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I updated relevant pictures in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you after such a long time. Did you add "@Test " to the line above the method? Maybe it's because this vscode can't search the required content.